# What is the method to use different programming languages in Eclipse?

Tags: java, c++, c, eclipse

I am trying to set up Eclipse that I follow below steps and I guess need some help :)

Firstly, I want to say that I've download JRE from here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html and set up jre-8u60-windows-x64.exe

Now, I am dealing with to download Eclipse but I cannot decide which IDE I should download from here: 
https://eclipse.org/downloads/ (My operating system is Windows 8.1 - 64 Bit)

Is there any difference between these IDEs? I want to Eclipse which contains Java and C/C++ programming for now and I might install other programming languages for the future. Which IDE must I download?

Comment: I usually download Java for EE, because it automatically has all the "normal Java" stuff (J2SE), as well as all the "web stuff" (JSPs, Tomcat, Java Enterprise (J2EE).  Then I just add the additional stuff I want (like CDT for C/C++, eGit for GIT connectivity, etc)

Comment: Each language is a plugin. Load as many language plugins as you like. In each of those downloads, eclipse is the same but it is just pre-loaded with different plugins for different needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find an `Eclipse` distribution that supports both `Java` and `C/C++` out of the the box.

If you want a single `IDE` for both, you can download the distribution for `Java`, and later install `C/C++` components.

`Eclipse IDE for Java Developers` is the basic Java IDE. `Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers` includes additional tools for developing Java Enterprise Edition applications such as `webapps` and `EJB`s. So, if you are a beginner or you mostly work on Java Standard Edition, download [Eclipse IDE for Java Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/marsr).

Then, as [this](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/788196/) post suggests, You can go to `Help -> Install New Software` menu item to install `C/C++` components.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the JAVA SE exactly? and what is the difference between "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" and "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers"?

Comment: @ Amila Well, if I download "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" can I do everything what I do in "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" and can I add it other programming languages as you said?

Comment: @ Amila Thank you so much

Comment: @NoWeDoR You will also need a C++ compiler. Path of least resistance with respect to Eclipse will be MinGW.